# multiple VBA if statements triggering different event

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, nested-if

Sorry i think this is pretty basic but I was wondering if somebody could tell me why only 1 of these **IF** statements seem to run. The 3rd **IF** statement for the **"CASH"** option works but the other 2 unfortunately don't.

```
Sub HideUnhide_Discount()

If Range("Payment_Option") = "Subscription" Then
    Range("MnthD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("MnthD").Value = 0
Else
    Range("MnthD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("Payment_Option") = "Lease" Then
    Range("OOD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("Leasing_Info").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("OOD").Value = 0
Else
    Range("OOD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("Leasing_Info").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("Payment_Option") = "Cash" Then
    Range("OOD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("MnthD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("OOD").Value = 0
Else
    Range("OOD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("MnthD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: they do, but when you reach the 3rd one it cancells the other two, your third `If` is not nested in the `Else` section of the first two

Comment: can you show any data?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint (F9) at the beginning on the first `If` line, and then F8-step through the code in the debugger, you'll discover that the `Else` block of the first two `If...End If` blocks executes when the first two conditions evaluate to `False`. That is probably not what you intended to write. In fact, it's not clear under which condition the `Else` blocks are supposed to run; the `Range("Payment_Option")` checks need to be in a `Select Case` or `If...Else If` block, and you need to figure out in which cases you need `MnthD_Row`, `Leasing_Info` and `OOD_Row` hidden.

Comment: In other words, [read your code to a rubber duck](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) to compare what it's actually doing vs what it's *supposed* to be doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing your multiple `If` >> `Else` condition with the `Select Case` below:

```
Sub HideUnhide_Discount()

' first reset all rows to be visible , later according to the value, unhide specific rows
Range("MnthD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Range("OOD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Range("Leasing_Info").EntireRow.Hidden = True

Select Case Range("Payment_Option")
    Case "Subscription"
        Range("MnthD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("MnthD").Value = 0

    Case "Lease"
        Range("OOD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("Leasing_Info").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("OOD").Value = 0

    Case "Cash"
        Range("OOD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("MnthD_Row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("OOD").Value = 0

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: this is great... just what i needed. Thank you